# Sticky navbar disappears on scroll

Tags: html, css

How can I make the sticky navbar stick to top of the page even after I provide a static height on sections below? Now when I scroll to the point of test-section then the nav disappears. How can I avoid this?

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.test-section {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>


<div class="header">
  hi navbar
</div>
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis et dolor tellus. Fusce laoreet nibh at nisl iaculis sollicitudin. Nullam dapibus, est vitae aliquet consectetur, velit ipsum vestibulum ante, et hendrerit enim erat non odio. Nullam sit amet nisi dictum, suscipit diam nec, pellentesque urna. Quisque semper turpis vitae suscipit eleifend. Mauris sed nisl at eros tristique accumsan vitae nec libero. Cras et laoreet mauris, eget posuere ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis et dolor tellus. Fusce laoreet nibh at nisl iaculis sollicitudin. Nullam dapibus, est vitae aliquet consectetur, velit ipsum vestibulum ante, et hendrerit enim erat non odio. Nullam sit amet nisi dictum, suscipit diam nec, pellentesque utur, ve

</p>
</div>
<div class="test-section">
<img src="https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/content/uploads/2018/02/The_City_London-scaled.jpg">

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you provide a static height to the `div` without constraining the image to not exceed it? if you put `max-height: 100%` on the `img` it gets scaled down to fill the container's height and the sticky header works as expected, but the question is: do you want to have the image at full height? if so, you can remove the height rule from its container; if not, prehaps you should consider adding a rule to prevent it from overflowing the container. Providing static height to a container and letting its children overflow is going to lead to unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128575/my-navbar-position-sticky-has-stopped-working-and-i-cant-figure-out-why You should get rid of the height you provided to your image. After 300px the nav-bar stops being fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use "position: fixed" instead on the class header

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `position: sticky;` to `position: fixed;` and also adding `width: 100%;` to your `.header` class seems to get the result your looking for

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background: blue;
}

.test-section {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>


<div class="header">
  hi navbar
</div>
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis et dolor tellus. Fusce laoreet nibh at nisl iaculis sollicitudin. Nullam dapibus, est vitae aliquet consectetur, velit ipsum vestibulum ante, et hendrerit enim erat non odio. Nullam sit amet nisi dictum, suscipit diam nec, pellentesque urna. Quisque semper turpis vitae suscipit eleifend. Mauris sed nisl at eros tristique accumsan vitae nec libero. Cras et laoreet mauris, eget posuere ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis et dolor tellus. Fusce laoreet nibh at nisl iaculis sollicitudin. Nullam dapibus, est vitae aliquet consectetur, velit ipsum vestibulum ante, et hendrerit enim erat non odio. Nullam sit amet nisi dictum, suscipit diam nec, pellentesque utur, ve

</p>
</div>
<div class="test-section">
<img src="https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/content/uploads/2018/02/The_City_London-scaled.jpg">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```